# make: pg_config: Not a directory make: *** No rule to make target 'installcheck'

Tags: database, postgresql, apache, apache-age

I installed postgres version 13 from source code using

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v13.5/postgresql-13.5.tar.gz && tar -xvf postgresql-13.5.tar.gz && rm -f postgresql-13.5.tar.gz

./configure --enable-debug --enable-cassert --prefix=$(pwd) CFLAGS="-ggdb -Og -fno-omit-frame-pointer"

make install
```

It installed sucessfully and I tried installing AGE  using `git clone https://github.com/apache/age.git`

Then I switched to the branch 1.3.0 using `git switch release/PG13/1.3.0`

from the AGE directory I set the PG_CONFIG environment variable to the pg_config path using `sudo make PG_CONFIG=/home/chidera/bitnine/postgresql-13.5/src/bin/pg_config install`

I keep getting this error `make: pg_config: Not a directory make: *** No rule to make target 'installcheck'.  Stop.`

when I run this `find / -name pg_config` command inside the directory where my postgresql was installed.
I get this as a response ./home/chidera/bitnine/postgresql-13.5/src/bin/pg_config

I am using WSL and ubuntu.

Comment: Install postgres development files before downloading tar file using `sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-all`. This error shows that your bin folder does not have the file pg_config. I faced the same error sometime ago and the fix suggested helped.

Comment: I think this is probably some WSL-specific defect.  Is this WSL1 or WSL2?  You should probably add a tag for it.  As far as I know, WSL1 is known to be broken for use with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing postgres development files by using this command
`sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-all`
before downloading the tar file as stated earlier by someone helped.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated this error on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS by running the commands you provided in the question, and what worked was removing `src/` from the directory that is pointing to PG_CONFIG like this:

`sudo make PG_CONFIG=/home/chidera/bitnine/postgresql-13.5/bin/pg_config install`

It is also good practice to set the following environment variables after installing PostgreSQL, replacing `/path/to/postgres` with your PostgreSQL installation directory:

```
export PATH=/path/to/postgres/bin:$PATH
export PGDATA=/path/to/postgres/bin/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `/pg_config` from your path.
The correct command should be

```
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/home/chidera/bitnine/postgresql-13.5/src/bin
```

Comment: I did as you stated, but this new error cropped up, make: I: No such file or directory
make: [Makefile:125: src/include/parser/cypher_kwlist_d.h] Error 127 (ignored)cc    -c -o src/backend/parser/cypher_keywords.o src/backend/parser/cypher_keywords.c
src/backend/parser/cypher_keywords.c:25:10: fatal error: postgres.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include "postgres.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/backend/parser/cypher_keywords.o] Error 1

Comment: Yes it seemed i made an error. You do need the `pg_config` an the end of the path. However when you installed postgres and u provided --prefix as a flag, what was the exact path of the $(pwd)?

Answer (score 0):

While running the `./configure` query before postgreSQL installation, specify the base installation directory as `pwd`(present working directory). It will install your postgreSQL in your custom directory i.e., **pwd** since you probably have multiple instances of posgreSQL installed.

```
./configure --prefix=$(pwd) --enable-cassert --enable-debug CFLAGS="-glldb -ggdb -Og -g3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
```

Repeat the next installation steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think as mentioned above there's a problem with the path youre providing currently for PF-CONFIG. So the first step is to check the path and its correctness, one way to do this is to run the following command

```
ls /home/chidera/bitnine/postgresql-13.5/src/bin/pg_config
```

The result of this should be pg-config file. If it doesnt return, then you have the installation again.

However, if the issue still occurs then try to install AGE as follows:

```
sudo make USE_PGXS=1 PG_CONFIG=/home/chidera/bitnine/postgresql 13.5/src/bin/pg_config install
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error while installing postgresql and I also use WSL Ubuntu.

Firstly, I would advice remove all previous installations using

```
make clean
```

And then reconfigure postgresql using

```
./configure --prefix=$(pwd) --enable-debug --enable-cassert
```

--prefix specifies where you want to install postgresql, and in this case it will be in the present working directory.

And then reinstall postgresql

```
gmake; gmake install;
```

After the installation you should see the `bin` directory in the pwd, the pg_config file is in the `bin` directory not in the `src/bin` directory.

And then you can try running PG_CONFIG again from your Age directory, this time try to use a relative path. Eg;

```
sudo make PG_CONFIG=../postgresql-13.5/bin/pg_config install
```

If postgresql and Age are in the same directory.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

follow these commands

```
make clean 
./configure   
 export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/:$PATH
    export PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/data
make -j8
make install -j8
sudo make PG_CONFIG=/postgresql-12.0/bin/pg_config install
```

now in age dir

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/pg/dist/postgresql-12.0/bin/";
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/pg/dist/postgresql-12.0/lib/"
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

So i just tried recreating your scenario on my system. kindly confirm the `pg_config` path. After installing i found two valid `pg_config` path, using the `find` command.

The first path being

```
postgresql-13.5/bin/pg_config
```

The second path being.

```
postgresql-13.5/src/bin/pg_config/pg_config
```

Setting any of the above path as your `PG_CONFIG` while running `make install` works for me. So i think the path you're using above is not the full path. Confirm that the pg_config path above is pointing to the `pg_config` executable file and not a directory, i think that seems to be the problem. The path you used is pointing to a directory not the actual executable file.